# Stripe issues when "pay with stripe" React Js method

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am following tutorial step by step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mOkFXyxfsU everything doing step by steps but when clicking on paying with stripe the window redirecting will pop up but that's it... when checking console I've got this errors

```
http://localhost:3000/api/stripe 400 (Bad Request)
```

In console I have

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
```

My code's so far

getStripe.js

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

let stripePromise;

const getStripe = () => {
  if(!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
  }

  return stripePromise;
}

export default getStripe;
```

stripe.js

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const params = {
        submit_type: 'pay',
        mode: 'payment',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        billing_address_collection: 'auto',
        shipping_options: [
          { shipping_rate: 'shr_1Lx6efBDBeK8mdWXxij3rOj5' },
        ],
        line_items: req.body.map((item) => {
          const img = item.image[0].asset._ref;
          const newImage = img.replace('image-','https://cdn.sanity.io/images/{id of sanity project}/production/').replace('-webp', '.webp');
          

          return {
            price_data: { 
              currency: 'usd',
              product_data: { 
                name: item.name,
                images: [newImage],
              },
              unit_amount: item.price * 100,
            },
            adjustable_quantity: {
              enabled:true,
              minimum: 1,
            },
            quantity: item.quantity
          }
        }),
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/success`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/canceled`,
      }

      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);

      res.status(200).json(session);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

Here is also whole code that was originally set up from this course similar to mine..: https://github.com/adrianhajdin/ecommerce_sanity_stripe

Thanks

I've tried to redo the course and even thought check original code from github but got this error..

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.
Issue was just with Stripe itself, you need to set your payment site before proceeding with payment, now it's working like a charm